# Can CoffeeScript Be Translated into This Piece of JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

```
function abc() {
    var a = 1;
    var func = function() {
        var a = 2;
    }
    func();
    alert(a);
}
```

Pay attention to the `var`, in the piece of code, the result of `a` will be 1, but if the `var` is omitted, the result will be 2, but I found Coffee not able to translate to this.

For example the following:

```
abc = ->
    a = 1
    func = ->
        a = 2
        return
    func()
    alert(a)
    return
```

Comment: Do you know about "variables scope" ?

Comment: @tangrui: is there a real use case to that? Maybe you could post that so we can work on your real problem?

Comment: It's really not very useful, but I have some legacy JavaScript code to translate to CoffeeScript, then I found this problem. The coffee snippet seems map the js, but it really doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CoffeeScript, by design, doesn't allow you to shadow a previously declared variable. Yet, there is one case where it still happens:

```
abc = ->
    a = 1
    func = (a) ->
        a = 2
        return
    func()
    alert(a)
    return
```

That will result in a `1`. Because `a` is function parameter, it's local to the function scope.

BTW, you could rewrite this as

```
abc = ->
    a = 1
    do (a) -> a = 2
    alert a
    return
```

where `do (a) -> a = 2` is equivalent to `((a) -> a = 2)()`.

Answer (score 5):

From the [CoffeeScript docs](http://coffeescript.org/#lexical_scope) (emphasis added):

> Because you don't have direct access to the var keyword, **it's
>   impossible to shadow an outer variable** on purpose, you may only refer
>   to it.

Is there a reason you need to shadow `a` and can't just use a different identifier?

Answer (score 4):

You can use backticks to execute normal js.

```
abc = ->
    a = 1
    func = ->
        `var a = 2`
        return
    func()
    alert(a)
    return
```

Compiled form

```
var abc;

abc = function() {
  var a, func;
  a = 1;
  func = function() {
    var a = 2;
  };
  func();
  alert(a);
};
```

Comment: Don't do that... it breaks the assumptions made by the compiler and may lead to unexpected results in future versions, even if it now seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you do this:

```
abc = ->
    a = 1
    func = ->
        b = 2
        alert(b)
        return
    func()
    alert(a)
    return
```

You get:

```
var abc;

abc = function() {
  var a, func;
  a = 1;
  func = function() {
    var b;
    b = 2;
    alert(b);
  };
  func();
  alert(a);
};
```

So just don't use the same variable name in the 2nd method scope and you are all good to go.

Answer (score 0):

What about the following code?

```
abc = ->
    a = 1
    func = ->
        @a = 2
        return
    func()
    alert(a)
    return
```

I agree: this is not strictly the same code, but behaves as expected...

Is your question just a stylistic composition or do you have a "real world" issue?

Comment: `@a` translates to `this.a` which in the given context equals the global object (`window` if in a browser). If executed in strict mode `this` instead equals `undefined` so execution would produce an error.

Comment: That's right. I was improperly assuming `abc` as a member function of a class. It was an intent to provide a solution that would keep the same variable name.

Anyway, this question does not really makes sense, as tangrui did not provided any explanation...